# Algorithm to fit divs on a page

Tags: javascript, algorithm, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to write an engine which will take 11 section(s) with varrying height and try to wrap them in a pdf (height: 1500 px/page).

Condition is that none of the underlying divs can span across two different pages, i.e. a div can either reside in page 1 and if it doesn't fit goes to page 2. No overlapping.

Objective is to minimize the blank space at end of every page (not at all, if possible).

Engine is supposed to reorder the underlying sections considering their height and suggest a combination of what page in pdf would hold how many and which sections.

Here is an example to illustrate the situation:

[image]

[image]

For example:

> Big 2 DIV and height = 1500px each

And some sections:

> section1 height: 600px
>
> section2 height: 1000px
>
> section3 height: 700px
>
> section4 height: 500px
>
> section5 height: 500px
>
> section6 height: 500px

So in first big div three combinations can get into it with minimum white space left. `section1 & section3` or `section1 & section4` or `section4 & section5 & section6`.

So now what will be the perfect logic to do this using jquery or javascript, or is their any plugin available like `isotope` or `masonry`

Based on my research, cutting stock algo seems to be match up with my requirements, please suggest if you have another approach or some psuedo code for cutting stock algo.

Thanks.

Comment: It is a bin unclear what is being asked; please consider rephrasing the question a bit.

Comment: I would guess you want some bin packing algorithm in JS, the question is not super clear to me, but try look at https://github.com/jakesgordon/bin-packing, something like that?

Comment: please refer my question again, I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

You need to rely on the CSS top and bottom properties. Here's a starting point for you in a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/X8JV9/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top color">child1</div>
    <div class="middle color">child2</div>
    <div class="bottom color">child3</div>
</div>

.container {
    height: 1500px;
    width:100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.color {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.top {
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.middle {
    top: 100px;
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
}

.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: no the problem is the big div height will be fixed, 1500px. So I want to put sections in it